# ModuleNotFoundError on Google Cloud Run, not locally

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-cloud-run

I am deploying a Python Flask application behind gunicorn on Google Cloud run. The container runs fine locally, but I notice when I build and push the service revision I get an error and my gunicorn workers crash:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

My directory structure is like so:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── gunicorn.conf.py
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── misc
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── daily_message.py
├── requirements.txt
└── server.py
```

I import the function `get_daily_message` in `server.py` like so:

```
from lib.misc.daily_message import get_daily_message
```

This all works fine locally and also when I build and run my container image locally.
Here is my Dockerfile.

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# Copy the entire project directory to the container.
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8080", "--workers", "2", "--threads", "4", "--timeout", "0", "server:app"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I am to answer my own question. After pulling down my artifact from Artifact Registry and inspecting it, I realized the `lib` directory was not being copied over. It turns out Google Cloud Build uses the `.gitignore` file to determine what to copy over along with a .dockerignore. The reason my module could not be found was because it wasn't copied over.

For context I was deploying to Cloud Run:

```
gcloud builds submit ...
gcloud run deploy ...
```